# Multiline UILabel - highlight certain range and truncate so that it is visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I am currently working on a search functionality in one of my apps and I am stuck trying to resolve a very annoying issue.

Lets assume that I have the following 2 paragraphs of text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin commodo tristique lectus in blandit. Vivamus felis odio, laoreet in lorem eget, mattis imperdiet lorem.
>
> Duis in nibh eleifend, lobortis mauris a, egestas odio.

When the user performs a search I will be displaying the results with a table view. The cells in this table view display 2 lines of text. In order to highlight the matching characters I am using attributed text and setting bold font for matching characters.

This all works well. However, I have one problem related to truncation. Lets suppose that the user searches for "egestas odio.". These words are located at the very end of the string, so, obviously, I would like to display the whole string and truncate its head.

Unfortunately, I cannot achieve this. Even though I set the correct truncation for `NSMutableParagraphStyle` which I am adding as an attribute of my attributed string, it doesn't work. I see the beginning of label with the tail being truncate instead of the head.

I have figured out that this problem is somewhat resolved if I remove all the newline characters. However, this is not very practical in my case.

Does someone know how I can overcome this obstacle? Alternatively, maybe you could give me some more general advise on how to implement the functionality that I need in a slightly different way. It seems fairly common and it is quite likely that there are some Open Source libraries which help to achieve this. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can truncate the middle by `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle`.

Comment: and what should I truncate when the user searches for "nibh eleifend" ? :) I would like to figure out the way to ensure that specified truncation works. Otherwise unexpected behaviour may persist

Comment: Do you intend to highlight multiple matching chars in a single cell? You can use Range to create a substring by getting the index of matching char.

Comment: I know how to do that. However, I also wish to display some text surrounding the matching characters in order to provide more context for users. Imagine that you have a collection of political articles and you are searching for "Trump". It is not very helpful if each cell shows "Trump" :) You do want to have a bit more context. For example, "Trump made a sensational announcement" or "Trump is under fire for his comments" or "New poll shows that Clinton has a lead over Trump".

Comment: I am saying that after getting the index of matching chars create a Range, with startIndex = matchingIndex - 20, endIndex = matchingIndex + 30. You will get a substring with .... "Trump"......

Comment: This solution is OK, but it is not ideal. I would like to display as much surrounding text as possible. Hard coding number of surrounding characters is therefore not ideal.

Comment: Refer this https://gist.github.com/Catherine-K-George/b1cdc0fbd5ebe6a91ad88c79d4ddebd7

Answer (score 0):

Given a string and a range you wanna keep, this walks in from either edge until the truncated string fits within a given size. You'll need to do additional work to recalculate the range within the truncated string.

**Swift 4**

```
func truncatedString(for text: String, with attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any], constrainedTo size: CGSize, keeping range: Range<String.Index>?) -> String {

    let nsString = NSString(string: text)

    var nsRange = NSMakeRange(nsString.length / 2, 0)
    if let range = range {
        nsRange = NSRange(range, in: text)
    }

    var truncatedString = nsString

    let elipsis = "..."
    let elipsisWidth = elipsis.size(withAttributes: attributes).width

    var shouldAddFrontElipsis = false
    var shouldAddBackElipsis = false

    var constrainedWidthIncludingElipsis = size.width
    if nsRange.location > 0 {
        shouldAddFrontElipsis = true
        constrainedWidthIncludingElipsis -= elipsisWidth
    }

    if NSMaxRange(nsRange) < nsString.length {
        shouldAddBackElipsis = true
        constrainedWidthIncludingElipsis -= elipsisWidth
    }

    var startIndex = 0
    var endIndex = nsString.length

    while (truncatedString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: constrainedWidthIncludingElipsis, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil).size.height > size.height) {

        if startIndex == nsRange.location && endIndex == NSMaxRange(nsRange) {
            break
        } else {

            if startIndex < nsRange.location {
                startIndex += 1
            }

            if endIndex > NSMaxRange(nsRange) {
                endIndex -= 1
            }

            truncatedString = NSString(string: nsString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)))
        }
    }

    if startIndex == 0 {
        shouldAddFrontElipsis = false
    }

    if endIndex == nsString.length {
        shouldAddBackElipsis = false
    }

    return (shouldAddFrontElipsis ? elipsis : "") + String(truncatedString) + (shouldAddBackElipsis ? elipsis : "")
}
```